# Infverif.exe error when copying files with the same name from different subfolders

Tags: windows, driver, inf

I have a driver which contains some files with the same name in several subfolders:

```
zh-hans\resources.dll
zh-hant\resources.dll
```

I want to copy those files into their dedicated subfolders.
To do so, I was expecting to do this kind of stuff in my inf:

```
...

[SourceDisksNames]
1="Installation Disk",,,

[SourceDisksFiles]
resources.dll=1,zh-hans
resources.dll=1,zh-hant

[DestinationDirs]
Resources_List_zh_hans = 11,\zh-hans
Resources_List_zh_hant = 11,\zh-hant

...

[Component_Install]
CopyFiles = Resources_List_zh_hans,Resources_List_zh_hant

[Resources_List_zh_hans]
resources.dll,zh-hans\resources.dll ; -> raise an error with infverif

[Resources_List_zh_hant]
resources.dll,zh-hant\resources.dll ; -> raise an error with infverif
```

This is working as expected (meaning I can sign, install my driver, the files will be copied properly), but infverif is raising 2 errors:

> Missing file 'zh-hans\resources.dll' under [SourceDisksFiles] section.

> Missing file 'zh-hant\resources.dll' under [SourceDisksFiles] section.

Is there a way to not raise this error message (expect by renaming my source files) ?

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/inf-sourcedisksfiles-section) you need to add the folder also in SourceDisksFiles, it seems like you are missing backslash

try this:

```
[SourceDisksFiles]
resources.dll=1,\zh-hans
resources.dll=1,\zh-hant
```

Comment: No I already tried this solution, for the same result.
(also tried to add backslash in my file list sections)

Comment: It seems in fact infverif want to find `zh-hans\resources.dll` in SourceDisksFiles.
If for example I add `zh-hans\resources.dll=1` and `zh-hant\resources.dll=1` it will no more complain (as if it was completely unaware of the subfolder...). But in this case my inf is really invalid, this tool seems to be out of date.